# jquery ui dialog doesn't call $.get inside dialog after first close of the dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a jquery ui dialog and inside of it I have another one
and before opening the one on the inside I call `$.get` to receive the html for it

if I open the first dialog and close it then open it again and try to open the dialog on the inside the html received from $.get doesn't get set

---

page1

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#bidialog").dialog({
                resizable: true,
                height: 500,
                width: 700,
                modal: true,
                autoOpen: false,
                buttons: { 'Anuleaza': function() { $(this).dialog('close'); } }
            });
        });

        function openit() {
            $.get('<%=Url.Action("Index", "Bank") %>', function(data) { $("#bidialog").html(data); })
            $("#bidialog").dialog('open');
        }

        $(function() { $("#bopen").click(openit); });

    </script>

    <div id="bidialog" title="the dialog">
        first content
    </div>
    <button id="bopen">
        openit</button>
```

---

page2

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#bcdialog").dialog({
            resizable: true,
            height: 400,
            width: 600,
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            buttons: { 'Anuleaza': function() { $(this).dialog('close'); } }
        });
    });

    $(function() {
        $("#create").click(createBank);
    });

    function createBank() {        
        $.get('<%=Url.Action("Create", "Bank") %>', function(data) { $("#bcdialog").html(data); })
        $('#bcdialog').dialog('open');
    }


</script>

<div id="bcdialog" style="display:none;" title="create bank">
    first content
</div>

<button class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" id="create">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-plus fl"></span>Adauga</button>
```

Comment: sorry not near enough to go on here, we need more code.

Comment: @redsquare I've edited my question, now it's everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If page2 is being loaded on document ready - during the first get: '<%=Url.Action("Index", "Bank") %>' - via ajax, then the document.ready methods of page2 would never get called (since the document is already ready).

FYI - The passing a function to jQuery $(function(){}); is the same as $(document).ready(function(){});

To get that code to execute, simply remove the jQuery wrapper since the code will get executed when it is loaded into the dom via the ajax call.

You can wrap the whole thing in an anonymous function if you need encapsulation:

```
(function () {
     $("#bcdialog").dialog({
        resizable: true,
        height: 400,
        width: 600,
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        buttons: { 'Anuleaza': function() { $(this).dialog('close'); } }
    });

    $("#create").click(createBank);

    function createBank() {        
        $.get('', function(data) { $("#bcdialog").html(data); })
        $('#bcdialog').dialog('open');
    }
});
```

Also, not sure of the big picture here, but you may want to consider using the 'live' jQuery events since they loosely bind to the selectors and will work even if the elements are removed and then added back to the dom.

```
$("#create").live("click" createBank);
```

Comment: the live thin made act really weird, when I was closing the popup on the inside i had to close it 3 times boefore it got closed, but removing the jquery wrapper for document ready on the page2 (that is loaded via ajax) helped

Comment: A call to live should be made only once. If continually calling a method to attach events then live is not a good choice. You would have to call "die" first to remove the live event (no kidding).